# randomForest in R - skip test

Tags: r, random-forest

I am working with package `randomForest`in R for predicting a price in an hourly basis.

For creating the model, after partitioning the dataframe, I use the following syntax:

```
  rf_regresor <- randomForest(x = train_df[c(all_predictors)],
                              y = train_df[,"target_variable"],
                              ntree = 50,
                              xtest = test_df[c(all_predictors)],
                              ytest = test_df[,"target_variable"],
                              mtry = 3,
                              importance = TRUE,
                              keep.forest = TRUE)
```

As the target variable to predict is a time series I would like for a specific purpose to train the model with all available data.

Let's say I have the `training data` from `"2017-01-01" to "2017-12-31"`. I would like to use the whole period for predicting the first week of 2018, that is, from `"2018-01-01" to "2018-01-07"` before `re-training` the model with the latest inputs.

Is it possible for the `xtest`, `ytest` part from the `randomForest` to be removed so I cna use the whole period?

If not, would it be reassonable to use all the period but one day and use the last day to test (altough we would not care about the result for that specific day)?

Thank you